# Log in to Stack Exchange via GitHub

Tags: bug, login, user-accounts, github

I always log in to Stack Overflow via my GitHub account.

If I am not logged in and want to post something on some other Stack Exchange site, as of today I cannot log in directly via GitHub, but if I log in on Stack Overflow I'm also logged in in all other Stack Exchange sites.

What is the intended behaviour in this case?
Is there a way to move my "via-GitHub" account to a direct Stack Exchange account to avoid this hassle?

Comment: I think using the email used in GitHub account you can login.